# Economics Online Seminars

Tags: reference-request, covid-19-crisis

As education moves to the internet, so are research seminars. Some of these seminars are regular and others appear to be temporary due to the covid-19 and the lockdown.

Here are some examples from the [American Economic Association](https://www.aeaweb.org/resources/online-seminars)

1. Regular seminar(s)

   - The [Chamberlain Seminar](https://www.chamberlainseminar.org/) - A regular open online international
     inter-institutional econometrics seminar in honor of Gary Chamberlain
     (1948–2020)
2. Temporary Seminars

   - [Virtual Macro Seminar Series](https://sites.google.com/view/virtualmacro/)
   - [Online Seminar in Gender Economics](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d8bT2V-QVsx5bz_r8uJGefM7xe5Qf9zs/view?fbclid=IwAR0AM210xvqY4855JujLPFIcReZhS9Y0nESamVMNdxIbD-rswEk2V8bOQgU)
   - [Virtual IO seminar](https://sites.google.com/view/virtual-io-seminar/)
   - ...

And also,

- [Princeton Webinar Series on COVID Economics](https://bcf.princeton.edu/event-directory/covid19/)

Beyond the AEA list and the Princeton webseminar, I am looking for links to find conferences, workshops, and talks hosted by economic research institutions from all over the world. One requirement is that registration be open to all, as some of the online seminars are reserved for faculty only.

---

Update

[Virtual Economics](https://virtual-econ.info/) stores various online seminars with a super useful **calendar**.

Answer (score 6):

I have two here to add to your list.

Brookings Insitute

https://www.brookings.edu/events/

St. Louis Fed  Economic lowdown
(FREE)

https://www.econlowdown.org/

There is also the National Association of Business Economics (NABE)
But to get access to their webinar resources you have to register on their site.
I know this won't qualify as it is not free but they are a good source of up-to-date information.  I felt that this would be a good share.

[www.nabe.com](http://www.nabe.com)

---

Others that I just found:
Peterson Institute for international Economics

https://www.piie.com/events

National Bureau of Economic Research (www.nber.org - click on videos) 
or

https://www.nber.org/video_archives.html

Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development (OECD)

http://video.oecd.org/

World Bank
https://www.worldbank.org/en/about/archives/past-events

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome friend.  If I find anymore I will update my post.

Answer (score 4):

In a few days, the Royal Economic Society in the UK is hosting

> [Economic approaches for analysing the short, medium term and long run impact of the COVID-19 crisis](https://www.res.org.uk/resources-page/res-policy-webinar-series.html)

featuring Daron Acemoglu and Jean Tirole.

Comment: Thanks that's great and also a little sad that the advent of webinars comes from a very bad outcome... But it wouldn't be the first time...

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice overview table with 33 econ webinar series (by April 10th) available here:

https://sites.google.com/view/econ-webinars/

Difficult for me to find out who is behind this great initiative.